# How create a Desktop and change between Desktops through shortcut keys in macOS?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using macOS 10.11 (El Capitan)

I am able to create and move between Desktops through the <kbd>F3</kbd> key and I can use the trackpad to move between the Desktops

But in Windows 10 I am able to do the following with the Keyboard:

- Create a new Desktop: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- Move between Desktops: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>

Is it possible to do the same in macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's never been a key command to create or destroy desktops, but that shouldn't impact you at all.

Simply create as many as you are likely to need, rather than destroy each after you've done with it. "Spare" Desktops/Spaces in themselves don't impact your environment at all, they can even help.

If you set up key commands, in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control you can instantly get to any of them. Every time you create a new Space, a new key command  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>[num]</kbd>   is created for it - but it is not enabled by default. Creating & destroying Spaces constantly will mean these never become permanently enabled.

Once created, you can assign specific Apps to specific Spaces. This is a major work-flow benefit, no longer do you have apps fighting for screen space.
To move an app to a Space, first switch to that Space then launch the App. Then right click it in the dock > Options > This Desktop [You'll note Apple use the terms Desktop & Space interchangeably]

One you have Apps assigned to Spaces, then all you need do to reach that App is hit the key command assigned to its Space number.

For a bit more detail, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme

Note that Fullscreening Apps removes any & all benefit that Spaces can supply. Fullscreens have no Space number & cannot be assigned a key command. For this [& many other reasons] I would never advise using Fullscreen for anything other than a temporary measure, such as watching a video, etc.

Comment: Was enabled from the beginning the _move to left_ and _move to right_ space or desktop. Well I have a minimum set of Desktops. Thanks for the other feedback/information

Comment: Move left/right is fine when you've only a couple of Spaces… the key commands really come into their own when you've half a dozen or more, rather than 5 sequential swipes or arrows to get from 1 - 6, you've one command.